# Super basic C++ Error

Tags: c++, file, compilation

I have this code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{

  wiringPiSetup ();

  char instructions[100];

  ifstream b_file ( "instructions.txt" );
  b_file>> instructions;
  cout<< instructions <<"\n";

}
```

As far as I understand it, this should compile to a program that outputs the contents of "instructions.txt" in the console...however, it won't even compile with g++ in Ubunutu...what's wrong?

Error messages tell:

```
"if_stream" wasn't declared in this scope
"b_ file" wasn't declared in this scope
"cout" wasn't declared in this scope.
```

Comment: When you have code which doesn't compile, and ask about it at SO, you should also include the error message, and indicate the error line in the question's code (because it does not have line numbers).

Comment: Not sure what SO is, but will do. No problem. Thanks, very new to C.

Comment: compilation error message ?

Comment: SO is short for Stack Overflow, ie this site :)

Comment: "if_stream" wasn't declared in this scope, "b_ file" wasn't declared in this scope, "cout" wasn't declared in this scope.

Comment: FWIW, [Clang tells you how to fix them](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d16ad64ac025034a).

Comment: Thanks so much. Will research exactly what "std" is.

Answer (score 2):

The obviours error is, you are missing `std` namespace. Two ways:

```
std::ifstream b_file ( "instructions.txt" );
b_file >> instructions;
std::cout << instructions <<"\n";
```

Another alternative is to add this *after* your includes, in the .cpp file:

```
using namespace std;
```

To explain a bit, `ifstream` and `cout` are defined in the *std* namespace, and are not found if you don't tell the compiler to look in there, using either of the above ways. Then `b_file` isn't defined properly, because of the `ifstream` not being found, so you also get error message about it.

Also, read up on C++ basics a bit... This is covered very early in any C++ learning material.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
using namespace std ;
```

to your code.

Note that both `ifstream` ans `cout` are from std namespace.

Or use

```
std::ifstream  
std::cout
```

insted